# access the input tag inside two div tags in dojo

Tags: jquery, dojo, dijit.form

```
var t=dojo.query(".classform")
```

gives me all the divs and input tag with the name classform.

t[0]=

```
<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox classofform" id="widget_country" role="presentation" widgetid="country" style="width: 5em; ">


<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
 <input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" name="textbox " type="text" tabindex="0" id="country" value=""></div>
```

now i want to access the input tag inside the two divs. which command should be used for that

Answer (score 0):

you can access your input tag inside two div using below code.

> var t=dojo.query("div #widget_country div input");

Comment: can i make it dynamic .... ? like i have many divs like the one above. and i want to access there input tag. is there any for loop which i can use

Comment: you can use it as "div div input". in my answer I have used # for id. you can use for specific as well as for any "div div input" also.

Comment: `dojo.query("div.classofform > div > input")`